# see if src of img exists

Tags: javascript, html, image, src

when I place an img tag I create the src attribute dynamically. Is there a way of testing if the src (path where the image is located) actually exists with javascript in order to avoid getting:

[image]

Comment: you may want to consider using a server side script to check for this as browsers can have javascript disabled.

Comment: Define "actually exists". Because of the cross-domain origin policy, you won't be able to examine the images the browser retrieves from the remote site using Javascript, so what you're asking for may be impossible. You can send the URL to the server and have it download the file, but that's a bad idea from a security standpoint.

Comment: I found this post. It should help you. http://www.irt.org/script/52.htm

Comment: I don't know why you people think I am doing this the wrong way. I have a folder where I place the common image extensions. for example I have an image named pdf.png, txt.png, .... etc many more. I have the most common ones and when the user uploads a file I will like to show a image of the file that he just uploaded. it is very easy to construct the img src just by knowing the file extension. I know I will be able to do this on the server side but it will require to much work. I will know display a default image for all the images that are unknown. Thanks a lot for help!

Answer (score 67, accepted):

You can use the `error` event:

```
var im = document.getElementById('imageID'); // or select based on classes
im.onerror = function(){
  // image not found or change src like this as default image:

   im.src = 'new path';
};
```

**Inline Version:**

```
<img src="whatever" onError="this.src = 'new default path'" />
```

Or

```
<img src="whatever" onError="doSomething();" />
```

---

`<img>` tag supports these events:

- `abort` (onAbort)
- `error` (onError)
- `load` (onLoad)

**More Information:**

- [JavaScript Events](http://www.comptechdoc.org/independent/web/cgi/javamanual/javaevents.html)
- [jQuery's `error`](http://api.jquery.com/error/)

Comment: I saw in other forums, that it doesn't work in IE, is that correct?

Comment: Right, thanks! Probably earlier versions, who knows xD thanks.

Comment: and what happens, when new_default_path doesn't exists? will it be an infinity loop?

Comment: I prefer doing it in other way so that the UI won't wait until `onError` to hide the image, causing the broken img icon to flash.
`<img src="somephoto.png" style="visibility:hidden;" onload="this.style.visibility='visible'" />`

Answer (score 16):

you can make a previous ajax call (with `head` method) and see the server return code
or you can use `onerror` event to change url or make it hidden, e.g.

```
<img src="notexist.jpg" onerror="this.style.visibility = 'hidden'">
```

(I've used inline attribute just to explain the idea)

Comment: Awesome example. Works like a charm.

Answer (score 6):

If you create the src dynamically with javascript you can use this:

```js
var obj = new Image();
    obj.src = "http://www.javatpoint.com/images/javascript/javascript_logo.png";

if (obj.complete) {
    alert('worked');
} else {
    alert('doesnt work');
}
```

Comment: The image exists in the following path, but it says 'no worky' when I run code snippet. Is it because of 'same origin policy'?

Comment: it is because, obj.complete return false. the code get executed right away. while the state isn't in complete yet. so it always go to else block

Answer (score 0):

easy

```
var x = new XMLHttpRequest(); x.open("get", "your_url.com/image.ext or /image.png or image.jpg", true);x.onreadystatechange = function () { if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {alert('exist');}else{alert('does not exist'};}; x.send();
```

Answer (score -1):

You're approaching this the wrong way.
When you generate your links with the server side script, check it there whether the file exists or not (by using `file_exists()` in PHP for example).

You shouldn't rely on JavaScript when you can do it in the server side, as JavaScript can be altered and disabled.

Ask yourself how are you generating the `src=` attributes, and check there whether the file exists or not, and provide an alternative.

Comment: This is very subjective: "You shouldn't rely on JavaScript when you can do it in the server side". I fully disagree, and the rationale is simply wrong. It's not because code can be altered that the user has an interest in doing so. The OP probably just wants to adapt the style of a web app if the image doesn't exist. Style is something that is in the client domain, and IMO, it should never occur server-side. Your point would be valid if the image was a secured resource that needed authentication to be displayed for example.