# JS check if img is not found

Tags: jquery, image

So, I have following js img var.

```
//Where `img_src` is another variable which actual image file MIGHT or MIGHT NOT exist.
var img_source = "/images/" + img_src;   
return '<img  src="' + img_source + '">';
```

Because `img_src` might or might not be available, sometimes I am getting `404 Not Found` error.

If there is no image, then I want to perform another function.

How do I check if the image file is available in this case?

I am trying to avoid showing the img attribute all together if image is not available. Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9022427/see-if-src-of-img-exists

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A jQuery way would be to listen to the `error` event:

```
var img = $("<img src='http://no-image.com/' />");

img.on('load', function(e){
    alert('Success!');
}).on('error', function(e) {
    alert('ERROR!');
});

img.appendTo("body");
```

https://jsfiddle.net/j70oybvy/

In pure JavaScript:

```
var img = document.createElement('img');

img.src='http://no-image.com/';

img.onload = function(e){
    alert('Success!');
};

img.onerror = function(e) {
    alert('ERROR!');
};

document.body.appendChild(img);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/j70oybvy/1/

Comment: A plus is that, if you change the `src` attribute of the image dynamically, the handlers will be called again.

Answer (score 6):

You could use a fallback img like so;

```
<img onerror="this.onerror=null; this.src='img/fallback.png'" />
```

To hide the element you can do so like this;

```
<img onerror="this.onerror=null; this.style.display = 'none'" />
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I am trying to avoid showing the img attribute all together if image is not available. Thanks!